# Как связать форму и модель

Tags: python, django

Всем привет.
Изначально была одна модель и в нее сохранялись данные из формы. Но позже решил разбить на 2 модели через ForeignKey: сотрудники и их отпуска. Через админку джанги все работает отлично - при создании отпуска в выпадающем списке выбираю фио и добавляю запись. Но не могу понять, как сделать, чтобы в мою форму создания отпусков выводились эти сотрудники, как в админке джанги. Вроде вычитал про forms.ModelChoiceField, но как описать не хватает мозгов.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Employee (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Vacation (models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vac_start = models.DateField(default="2018-01-01", null=True)
    vac_dur = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=14, null=True)
    vac_end = models.DateField(default="2018-01-14")
```

Forms.py:

```
from django import forms


class UserForm(forms.Form):
    employee = forms.CharField(label="ФИО", required=True)
    vac_start = forms.DateField(label="Отпуск с", widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date'}))
    vac_duration = forms.IntegerField(label="Дней отпуска", widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'number', 'min': 7, 'max': 14}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так. В [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) можете узнать про то какие еще аргументы принимает поле.

```
# Не забудьте импортировать Employee.
# Например так (если models.py и forms.py лежат в одной директории)
from .models import Employee


class UserForm(forms.Form):
    employee = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Employee.objects.all())
    # другие поля формы
```

Comment: Блин, да как так. Первым же делом такое попробовал. Писало ошибки.
А сейчас после вашего ответа все нормально ) Спасибо!

Comment: Хотя наверное все же дописал в тот раз, т.к. меня смутило что он подсвечивает objects с текстом unresolved attribute for class Employee. До этого пробовал вот так queryset=Employee.name